# Sharepoint server publishing feature was activated but not show hide ribbon in Site Actions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, publishing-site

Sharepoint server publishing feature was activated on one of my SharePoint sites, but it's not showing hide ribbon in Site Actions.

Also when we edit the page, it's appending the parameters “?PageView=Shared&InitialTabId=Ribbon.WebPartPage&VisibilityContext=WSSWebPartPage” to the address bar insted of  "?ControlMode=Edit&DisplayMode=Design".

**NB** : In the navigation setting the "Ribbon" and "Hide Ribbon" commands are already set as "true"

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be similar to that reported here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/35c7f486-2b20-4129-b461-65b147a4490e/when-editing-the-page-in-sharepoint-we-cannot-edit-the-content-area-and-we-need-to-click-on-save-and?forum=sharepointgeneral

We found your issue and the solution because when our users edited a sharepoint online page they got take to
intranet/pages/somepage.aspx?PageView=Shared&InitialTabId=Ribbon.WebPartPage&VisibilityContext=WSSWebPartPage

Which showed them a view of the page with no ribbon and no ability to edit the content.
On some pages they were shown the ribbon. In thoses cases they still couldn't edit the content until they clicked the "save and keep editing" option from the ribbon save button. When they did this they were taken to
intranet/pages/somepage.aspx?ControlMode=Edit&DisplayMode=Design

After going through the solution outlined on technet (turn publishing off and turn it on again) our users now experience : edit page taking them to full ribbon, and editable content without a URL suffix i.e. they end up at the following when they edit the page 
intranet/pages/somepage.aspx

Hope this helps someone